# Why is kubernetes taking so long to start a container when a postStart hook is defined?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a simple deployment with two containers defined, where one of them have a postStart hook defined.

It takes like 4 minutes before it even **starts** the second container (`mysql:8`), while the first image starts in about 5 seconds. I base this on the information from `kubectl describe pod ...`

The image is already present on the node, it's a single node with 4 cpus. And it's only running 2 deployments (so eventually 4 containers in total).

4 minutes seems completely excessive, how can I reduce this time?

Answer (score 0):

I had a postStart lifecycle hook defined, which apparently blocks the start of further containers (until it the postStart command fails??).

It's also confirmed by [this article](https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/delaying-application-start-until-sidecar-is-ready-2ec2d21a7b74) here:

> This is where the post-start lifecycle hook comes in. It turns out that the Kubelet code that starts the container blocks the start of the next container until the post-start handler terminates.

---

OKAY so surely I can just do a:

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/anything ]; then echo "anything" > /tmp/anything; exit 1; fi;
```

Which will `exit 1` the first time the postStart command is run, and then finally start the rest of the containers??

Well no it seems the the `postStart` hook does not fire AFTER THE CONTAINER IS STARTED, only once it seems to be ready.

---

So to work around this, we instead will use bash (the battle tested process control over multiple decades)

In the entrypoint script, you just do a `postStartScript.sh &`, and we can remove this confusing/buggy postStart hook. The only limitation to this is that if our postStartScript runs into any errors, it won't necessarily be integrated into any of the pods health / status (only some error message might be logged in the logs)...